# Are there cases where it is correct to use "more" with a monosyllabic adjective?

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

In general, it appears monosyllabic adjectives in English form the comparative by the *-er* suffix.  Are there any cases where a monosyllabic adjective can be preceded by *more* but still be grammatical (it might be an adverbial use possibly?)?

Edit: I've thought of some cases where the adjective is modifying something, for example:

> 1. There are more fast cars today than ever.
> 2. More big companies are choosing Verizon as their phone carrier.

Still, are there any other cases?

Comment: Note that in your examples, we are not dealing with a comparative of the adjective. *More* is here a determiner meaning 'an amount or number that is larger than another' (Macmillan online dictionary)

Comment: In your examples, _more_ modifies _cars_ and _companies_, respectively, not _fast_ and _big_. They aren't necessarily faster or bigger than before — just more of them.

Comment: This is what was meant by "the adjective is modified something", which meant to mean "the adjective is modifying something."

Comment: Adjectives aren’t special in this way.  The very same question applies to adverbs as well, which not only inflect into the comparative degree faster than you can shake a stick, but sooner, too.

Answer (score 4):

In your example sentences *more* is being used as a determiner not as a comparative. The meaning is: *Today there are more cars that are fast*, and not *Today there are faster cars*.

There is in fact one context in which *more* is sometimes used in the comparative of single-syllable adjectives, namely as an alternative to the repetition of the adjective in sentences such as:

> It's becoming more and more clear to me that I may be in trouble one
>   day. (clearer and clearer)
>
> Why is it that the rich are getting more and more rich, and the poor
>   getting more and more poor? (richer and richer / poorer and poorer)

And there is another context in which it is mandatory to use *more*, such as in the following:

> She was more dead than alive. (*She was deader than alive.)
>
> Germany's grey manifesto is more old than bold. (*Germany's grey
>   manifesto is older than bold.)

Answer (score 0):

IN the 100 most common *more + adjective* citations in the *Corpus of Contemporary American English*, there is only one single-syllable adjective, *real*, and that has two syllables for many speakers. *More fun* appears in the list, but many of the citations are for the noun.

So, the construction is not common, but Quirk et al note in their *Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* that it's possible. They specifically mention some adjectives for which it is rare: *bad, big, black, clean, fair [colour], far, fast, good, great, hard, high, low, old, quick, small, thick, thin, tight, wide, young.*

Comment: if dipthongs are allowed, then I wouuld add the tripyhongs "royal" and "loyal". There is also the case of past participles used as adjectives, e.g, "my shoes are more worn than his".

Comment: @Martin  
*Royal* and *loyal* have no triphthong: they both have two syllables, and to be a triphthong you need **three vowel sounds *in a single syllable.*** So things like *why, weigh, wow, yay.*

Comment: @tchrist Who says they've got two syllables?

Comment: @tchrist The last element used in the representation of *fire* is represented with a schwa, that does not prevent it from being a thriphthong for the majority of speakers in normal speech. Strictly speaking a thriphthong is one single glide with a changing target, in other words it changes direction half way through. We can't *really* view it as two glides just like we can't view a diphthong as being two vowels. If *fire*'s a triphthong for some speakers, the same's going to be true at least for some speakers for 'loyal' it seems.

Comment: @tchrist Don't worry I'll leave it here: If you want to contradict a British English speaking poster about their post, your comments need to hold water for British English speakers - it would seem.

Comment: @tchrist. "this is a British heresy unshared by Scots or Americans"**?**. Scots were British the last time I heard.

Comment: @tchrist: even for Americans, *royal* can be one syllable (assuming *foil* is). I rhyme *foil* with *royal*.

Comment: @tchrist: your "I refuse to argue about it" does seem to shut out the possibility of discussion here. Your "even the non-rhotic VGV is two syllables when looked at from an American perspective " seems to suggest that other non (un?) American points of view are not worth considering. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: @tchrist. Sorry. I thought I was asking a question.

Comment: @tunny There’s probably room for a whole question about the root cause behind conflicting syllabic analyses, but a cascading comment chain isn’t the place for it.  When talking about the Mayan Indians, for example, that first word has two syllables while the second one (usually) has three (in English).  So for example with *Maya*, you have a classic CVGV pattern yielding a two-syllable analysis: there **cannot** be a triphthong there because there are two different syllabic nuclei separated by a glide. It makes no never-mind that the second syllable being unstressed suffers standard reduction.

Comment: @tchrist. "...there cannot be a triphthong there...". An interesting opinion, but that's all it is - an opinion. I don't agree, but my opinion is just that - an opinion.

Comment: @tchrist  I have already asked a question that you appear not to have noticed: *Your "even the non-rhotic VGV is two syllables when looked at from an American perspective " seems to suggest that other non (un?) American points of view are not worth considering. Is this what you are saying?*

Comment: @Araucaria Well, [John Wells](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/12/triphthongs-anyone.html) for one, who mostly disavows triphthongs in English. He has also written extensively on [varisyllabicity](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/11/diphthong-schmiphthong.html). Look at the inventories compiled in UPSID and in SPhA; then read the various analyses made of these findings. You seem to prefer the Ladefoged definition over the Catford one, but serious conflicts exist in the professional linguistics literature regarding definitions and practical uses of these terms.

Comment: @tunny I once again kindly invite you to post a proper question using the **Ask Question** link. This is not something to be dorked around with in comments.  And I am very unhappy with being rudely cornered by strawmen of things I haven’t said; however, I will consider your apology if and when presented. Until you post a proper question via **Ask Question**, I have nothing more to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18711/discussion-between-tunny-and-tchrist).

Answer (score 0):

A different and probably better example could be

> This is a car more fast than fast-selling.

(Made for speed but few people want to buy.)

The benefit of *more* rather than the comparative form *faster* is too obvious here.

There are contexts where *more* and *most* are useful irrespective of whether the word itself has its own comparative and superlative forms because the semantic is different.